# How to fix error 905 in play store?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean

I can't download large apps like CSR racing, Asphalt 8, and Trial Xtreme due to error 905. I tried to uninstall  play store updates but as soon it reinstalls error 905 occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem and he solved it in this way 
Tap "Menu"> "Settings"> "Applications"> "Manage Applications"
Tap on the tab "All"
Scroll down and select the "Google Play Store" app from.
Tap on "uninstall updates".
then install your app Google Play market again and then it should work...try again and contact customer support